# Passage of a reference to a pointer for base classes

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, pass-by-reference

I have a class `Child` that extends `Base`. In my class `Foo` I have methods with the signature like:

```
void Foo::doStuff(Base *& base);    // case A
void Foo::doOther(Child *& child);  // case B
void Foo::doSomething(Base * base); // case C
```

I have no problems with the *case B*. 
If I write:

```
Child * myChild = new Child();
Foo foo;
foo.doOther(myChild);
```

There is no compile/runtime error.

The problem is with the *case A*, if I write:

```
Child * test = new Child();
Foo foo;
foo.doStuff(test);
```

I get a compile time error message:

> error: no matching function for call to foo::doStuff...

There is no problem in case I am not using a reference to a pointer (*case C*)

I have also tried to cast the test object to a `Base *&` object before the call to `doStuff`, but I would like to make it work like *case C*.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

It is: Child * myChild = new Child(); //not Base * myChild = new Child();

Comment: Can you share the implementation of Child?

Comment: The code should compile without errors. Maybe you have `Child * test = new Child()`?

Comment: It's very long, here I have just written a basic test case. It gives the same error even with an empty method (everything commented)

Comment: @Henrik you're right I have that, I'll edit the post..

Comment: Just modifying Child * test = new Child(); with Base * test = new Child(); it solves the problem but I would like to know why it works if I use just standard pointers

Answer (score 5):

If this

```
Child * test = new Child();
Foo foo;
foo.doStuff(test);
```

would be allowed, and `doStuff` is implemented like this:

```
Foo::doStuff(Base *& base)
{
    delete base;
    base = new Base();
}
```

Then you would end up with a pointer statically typed as `Child *` but really pointing to a `Base`.

This

```
Child * test = new Child();
Foo foo;
foo.doSomething(test);
```

is not a problem, because `doSomething` cannot modify `test`.

Comment: Cheers mate, your explanation has been really clear. The compiler complains were right. The solution so is to declare all the object of Base* type. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `Child` "is-a" `Base` does not mean that a `pointer-to-Child` "is-a" `pointer-to-Base`. Inheritance does not propagate to pointer, for a good reason.

Imagine `doStuff` is implemented as follow:

```
void doStuff(Base *& base)
{
    base = new Base;
}
```

If you were able to pass a pointer to `Child` to this function, you would end up with a pointer pointing to an object of the wrong type:

```
Child *pChild;
doStuff(pChild);
// pChild now points to a Base and not a Child!
```

Comment: thank you too. You were really helpful and I have to admit that this C++ theme is really interesting...